# Localization works on localhost but not in production enviroment

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have this website with english and portuguese support.
In localhost everything works fine and the content is translated based on the querystring parameter named "lang".

This chunk of code makes the trick in every page:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
     SetCulture();
}

private void SetCulture()
{
    var logger = Util.GetLogger();

    string lang = Request.QueryString["lang"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang)) { lang = "pt-br"; }

    string sessionLang = (string)Session["lang"];


    if (sessionLang != lang)
    {
        Session["lang"] = lang;
    }

    logger.Log(string.Format("Culture {0} found",lang));

    UICulture = lang;
    Culture = lang;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);

    logger.Log(string.Format("Cultura {0} set", lang));

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Thanks to the logger I can say for sure that this method is called in both cases (production and localhost).

I have two resources files in App_GlobalResources folder:
-WebSitemapGlobal.en-us.resx;
-WebSitemapGlobal.resx;

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are little confused about localization in .NET.

First, if `WebSiteMapGlobal.resx` is in Brazilian Portuguese, there is no need to specify `pt-br` as culture, since the culture is **neutral**

Probably, the problem is due to calling `base.InitializeCulture()` after setting language. You should also have posted a little log about your page execution.

Also, a software engineering tip: you should call `base.InitializeCulture()` from void `InitializeCulture()` after `SetCulture()`. The result is identical (I just asked you to remove that call anyway) but it's a very good practice to call a base method from its override.